# Printing index of dictionary items

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm working on an assignment, in which I have to print out the contents of an address book, with each item numbered sequentially. The address book is a nested dictionary:

```
addressBook = {'Jim': {'name': 'James Marsh', 'address': '32 Morris Ave',
                           'phone': '6549873217'},
    'Leanne': {'name': 'Leanne Moss', 'address': '37 Shamrock Lane',
                           'phone': '1234567890'},
    'Chris': {'name': 'Christopher Philips', 'address': '49 Langley Court',
                           'phone': '3216549870'}}
```

My function for listing the contents currently looks like this:

```
def listAll(addressBook):
    for key, value in addressBook.items():
        print(key)
        print(value['name'])
        print(value['address'])
        print(value['phone'])
```

which outputs

```
Jim
James Marsh
32 Morris Ave
654-987-3217

Leanne
Leanne Moss
37 Shamrock Lane
123-456-7890

Chris
Christopher Philips
49 Langley Court
321-654-9870
```

The specification for the assignment, states that they have to be numbered sequentially, as in

```
1    Jim
James Marsh
32 Morris Ave
654-987-3217

2    Leanne
Leanne Moss
37 Shamrock Lane
123-456-7890

3    Chris
Christopher Philips
49 Langley Court
321-654-9870
```

I've tried

```
for index, key, value in enumerate(addressBook.items()):
    print(str(index+1) + '\t' + key)
    print(value['name'])
    print(value['address'])
    print(value['phone'] + '\n')
```

but that gives a `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)` error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack that with:

```
for index, (key, value) in enumerate(addressBook.items()):
```